# How to remove extra image displayed in Windows Phone Emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

[image: Captured From Emulator]

![enter image description here]

When i run my app, the emulator display some unwanted images or text in the top right corner

as shown in the above picture(indicate by red mark).

What is this image or text?

How can i remove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These numbers are [Frame rate counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg588380%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). You can enable/disable them in `App.xaml.cs`:

```cs
// Show graphics profiling information while debugging.
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    // Display the current frame rate counters.
    Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;

    // other code…
}
```

Comment that line or change value to `false` to remove the counters.